# Composer network start [ssl certificate error] after providing .npmrc file

Tags: node.js, npm, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to deploy a sample business network from behind a corporate proxy. I am following the developer tutorial provided. While running the command

*composer network start --networkName tutorial-network --networkVersion 
 0.0.1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --card 
 PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --file networkadmin.card -o 
 npmrcFile=/Users/user/.npmrc*

I get the following error

*Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed*

Docker logs show the following error for a new container trying to install something using npm commands

```
*2018-07-22T03:00:58.228907438Z npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.6.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=2.16.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
2018-07-22T03:01:06.734626419Z 
> x509@0.3.3 install /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
> node-gyp rebuild
2018-07-22T03:01:06.734705076Z 
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1103:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:637:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:467:38)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN tutorial-network@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN The package composer-common is included as both a dev and production dependency.
2018-07-22T03:01:07.835711840Z 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! x509@0.3.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the x509@0.3.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.*
```

Logs from peer container

```
2018-07-22 03:00:34.761 UTC [container] lockContainer -> DEBU 64a got container (dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1) lock
2018-07-22 03:00:34.762 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 64b Cleanup container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1
2018-07-22 03:00:34.762 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 64c Stop container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1(No such container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1)
2018-07-22 03:00:34.763 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 64d Kill container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1 (No such container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1)
2018-07-22 03:00:34.763 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 64e Remove container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1 (No such container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1)
2018-07-22 03:00:34.763 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 64f Start container dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1
2018-07-22 03:00:34.763 UTC [dockercontroller] createContainer -> DEBU 650 Create container: dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1
2018-07-22 03:00:34.765 UTC [dockercontroller] Start -> DEBU 651 start-could not find image <dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1-6695b9314667cc296171c0da511644e9011aa9a3ba0f6e759aca9e32e458803c> (container id <dev-peer0.org1.example.com-tutorial-network-0.0.1>), because of <no such image>...attempt to recreate image
2018-07-22 03:00:34.765 UTC [chaincode-platform] generateDockerfile -> DEBU 652 
FROM hyperledger/fabric-baseimage:x86_64-0.4.6
ADD binpackage.tar /usr/local/src
LABEL org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.id.name="tutorial-network" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.id.version="0.0.1" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.chaincode.type="NODE" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.version="1.1.0" \
      org.hyperledger.fabric.base.version="0.4.6"
ENV CORE_CHAINCODE_BUILDLEVEL=1.1.0
2018-07-22 03:00:34.766 UTC [util] DockerBuild -> DEBU 653 Attempting build with image hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-1.1.0
```

.npmrc configuration

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
strict-ssl=false
unsafe-perm=true
ca=
rejectUnauthorized=false
proxy=my proxy
https-proxy=myproxy
```

My configuration

```
Mac OSX High Sierra
composer-cli 0.19
Hyperledger fabric version 1.1
Using a corporate firewall
```

Although there are numerous posts with similar issues. None of them have been able to solve my issue. Any help, guidance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Set the following [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable): `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` (or `export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`).

Comment: Hi Andy, I have the export command in my bash_profile as well as in .npmrc file. However, I am getting the same problem.  As the composer network start tries to do npm install from docker container, Do i need to explicitly provide npm config to docker ?

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to provide the npmrc file as part of the start command, which won't work. it should be passed as part of the install command

`composer network install -a mybn.bna -c myadmin@fabric-network -o npmrcFile=/Users/user/.npmrc`

Comment: Hi David, I provided the .npmrc file in network install and it still has the same error