# composer network start command failed

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

`suma@ubuntu:~/poc/land$ composer network start --networkName property-network --networkVersion 0.2.6-deploy.113 --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -A admin -S adminpw --file networkadmin.card
Starting business network property-network at version 0.2.6-deploy.113`

> Processing these Network Admins: 
>       userName: admin
>
> ✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
>   Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
>   Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to execute transaction ae276da81f756ac76edccf85a79f1c11a554f1285c2a8c4cc2899db433220500: error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "npm WARN notice [SECURITY] hoek has the following vulnerability: 1 moderate. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=hoek&version=2.16.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
>   npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
>   npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
>   npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
>   npm WARN deprecated boom@4.3.1: This version is no longer maintained. Please upgrade to the latest version.
>
> x509@0.3.3 install /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
>   node-gyp rebuild
>
> gyp ERR! configure error 
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:483:19)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:397:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
>   gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
>   gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
>   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
>   gyp ERR! System Linux 4.10.0-28-generic
>   gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd /chaincode/output/node_modules/x509
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.4.0
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
>   gyp ERR! not ok 
>   npm WARN The package composer-common is included as both a dev and production dependency.
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! x509@0.3.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the x509@0.3.3 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-12-19T06_43_46_434Z-debug.log
>   "
>   Command failed

`FABRIC_VERSION=hlfv12
COMPOSER_VERSION=v0.20.5
NODE_VERSION=v8.14.1
NPM_VERSION=6.4.1`

I already done ./teardownfabric and ./stopFabric and again started a fabric and create a peeradmin card .

Comment: hi there, can you update your question with info required from here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#issue  as well as the Fabric version you are using. Also are you behind a firewall, did you supply an npmrcFile to the `composer network install` command sequence if so ? See also the ANSWERS in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51461710/composer-network-start-ssl-certificate-error-after-providing-npmrc-file

Comment: The first `ERR!` seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by an old or incorrect image used to build chaincode images. As long as you haven't reconfigured your peer to use a different build image then the easiest fix for this is to delete any `ccenv` images you might have for example you could try

```
docker rmi $(docker images hyperledger/fabric-ccenv* -q) -f
```

to force remove all ccenv images